# Elixir pattern match protocol implementor

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir, protocols

You can pattern match specific structs in your methods to prevent some leakage of type bugs. E.g. `def f(z_struct = %Z{}) do ...`.

Can you do something similar if you don't know the type of struct, say, if you want a struct of a module that implements protocol `P`.?

```
defprotocol P do
  # ...
end

defmodule A do
  defstruct :a
end
defimpl P, for: A do
  # ...
end

defmodule B do
  defstruct :b
end
defimpl P, for: B do
  # ...
end

defmodule SomeMod do
  def m(p) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

I.e. method `SomeMod.m/1` should accept only an %A{} or a %B{} as parameter. If module `C` implements `P` later, `m/1` should accept `C` without code changes.

Can we do this elixir?

---

If the above doesnt explain well, think of it like accepting an interface in Java, where `P` is the interface and `A` and `B` are the classes that implement `P`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is impossible with guards / pattern matching in function clauses. The only way to assert this would be to use a reflection [`Kernel.impl_for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defprotocol/2-reflection):

```rb
defmodule SomeMod do
  def m(p) do
    unless P.impl_for(p), do: raise MatchError, term: p
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I have even a blog post written on the subject: [this would be another approach to pattern match protocols](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2018/01/03/pattern-matcher-for-protocols).

Comment: Interesting article. Couldnt we use a macro as a wrapper around the `impl_for` function so we could use it in the guard? It would mean we would have to write `require ModuleContainingTheMacro` which is kind of annoying, but it would require less code. It also would be restricted to a single parameter

Comment: I am not sure I follow. We cannot use `impl_for` in the guard in the first place.